# Please help me in solving jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, easyslider

I have created a slideshow using jquery easyslider. But its not happening. I am not able to find where exactly the problem.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

..and the corresponding HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>                
        <li><img src="Beauty/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Beauty/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Beauty/3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Beauty/4.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="Beauty/5.png" /></li>         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should tell us what the expected behaviour is. Anyway, I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null*. And please include the relevant part of your JS code in your post.

Comment: I am using easySlider1.7.js and its too big to post. How do i post?

Comment: @mythri: You should not post the code of `easySlider1.7.js`, but the **relevant** code you have written. *How do i post?*: Edit your question and add the code.

Comment: all the images one after another are getting displayed instead of slideshow.

Comment: @mythri: I don't even see images...

Comment: I don't see images either. I get the following error `Error: lyr is null
Source File: http://netelityeasylife.com/bodhitree/js/dw_scroll.js
Line: 22`

Comment: @John: Here it is opening, i mean not the images but only prev and next buttons are opening . Dont know why. Am not able to rectify the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted here is working. I've setup a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/jFePh/

Looking at your code in the HTML pages there are a couple of problems.

1. The images don't actually exist so you wouldn't know whether it's working properly anyway
2. Your show/hide code doesn't seem to be working (`toggleMe('para2')` I think). It doesn't actually show all the containers.
3. `#slider` remains hidden and the UL inside just keeps switching between `pt/px`.

Your markup seems to be ok, but your JS is not working as you expect. There's a lot of JS that's been included at the top of the page, by Dreamweaver I assume. You might want to clean out all that and get the basics working before you add any functionality to the page.

**EDIT**

The problem you're having is related to how easySlider figures out the dimensions.

You start out with

```
<div id="para3" style="display:none">
```

When the easySlider code kicks in, it tries to figure out the dimensions. Since the height and the width are set to 0 it figures it can't actually do the slideshow and gives up (*this is an oversimplification*)

This can be seen in this fiddle I setup : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/jFePh/2/

The solution for this would be to remove the `display:none` from your DIVs and hide it using JS **AFTER easySlider has loaded and done its bit**.

So to fix this problem.

1. Remove the  `style` attribute and add a class so it looks like this `<div id="para1" class="hideMeLater">`
2. Change the JS at the top of your document so it looks like the below

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
           auto: true, 
           continuous: true
        });
        $('.hideMeLater').hide();//hiding all the divs we removed display:none from
    });
```

This *should* do fix your slideshow problem. I've set up a fiddle with a sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/jFePh/3/

As an aside, I suggest you get familiar with JS and jquery so that you understand what is actually happening when you include plugins. There are some excellent tutorials available on the net.

Also, you should clean up your HTML.

Comment: @John: Thank you.. Will just do it and try.

Comment: If i remove the hide/show option (toggleMe('para2'), it works properly. But i want it with the hide/show option. How can i do it?

Comment: You should move the logic of the `toggleMe` method to jquery and let it handle it.

Comment: I am not getting how to change it :(. Can you please help me

Comment: I've added a clarification. You should be able to figure out how to fix it now

Answer (score 0):

you have `id="slider"` more than one elements try to give unique id..
i think thn it will work...

Comment: If i remove the hide/show option (toggleMe('para2'), it works properly. But i want it with the hide/show option. How can i do it? –